# html5 validation - valid when the value is NOT equal to a certain string

Tags: jquery, regex, html, validation

I have an html input that is required and I am setting a pattern on the input dynamically using jQuery, like this:

```
let theString = 'test'

$('input[name="string"]').attr("pattern", theString)
```

this works fine, the input is only valid when its value is exactly equal to: `test`

How can I do the reverse of this? I would like it only to be valid if the value is anything other than: `test`

Comment: You can: `if(!(totest.indexOf('test') > -1)){ // means test is not within the string }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to reverse this regex. Bare in mind there are still very simple ways around this, and you should rely on a backend validation rather than a frontend validation when submitting forms.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="string" required/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
    $(function() {
        let theString = '^(?!test$).*';

        $('input[name="string"]').attr("pattern", theString);
    });
</script>
```